# What are good resources for learning the Zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

What's an efficient way for someone who knows PHP and Ruby on Rails to quickly pick up the Zend framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that by already having experience with RoR and PHP, you have already broken the back of the task.  RoR follows the same architecture pattern as the Zend Framework (MVC); and so you will already have an abstract understanding of your first Zend Framework application.

I don't know of any resources that are specifically targeted at transitioning RoR programmers to Zend Framework programmers (that would make a good topic for a book), however, with (at least) a syntactic understanding of PHP, I'd recommend you read one of the following introduction articles:

1. [The Official Quick-Start Guide](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart)
2. [Rob Allen's Getting Started with Zend Framework 1.8](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/)

You can always post questions on S.O. if you're stuck!

Comment: Thanks for Rob Allen's guide.  I had done the quick start previously, and felt pretty comfortable with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add the [nabble forum](http://www.nabble.com/Zend-Framework-Community-f16154.html) dedicated to ZF that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also like to point out the FREE Zend Framework Book found in: http://www.survivethedeepend.com